# MOSEK license error

Tags: licensing

I am trying to solve a linear optimization problem and thought that I'll use MOSEK to see if theres any speed improvement. So I obtained a MOSEK academic license, and saved the .lic file at /Users/USERNAME/mosek/mosek.lic. Then I ran the following code

```
SetEnvironment[
 "MOSEKLM_LICENSE_FILE" -> 
  FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "mosek", "mosek.lic"}]]
```

However, mathematica did not recognise this license and using `Method -> "MOSEK"` in optiimization problem outputs a license error. I am using 13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need `SetEnvironment`. Restart your computer. Mathematica automatically run  MOSEK license from HOME directory.

Comment: I tried that but it doesnt work

Comment: Fortunately it works on my computer. What problem do you solve? Could you show part of your code with MOSEK call?

Comment: I tried to run the demo code `NMinimize[{x^2 + 2 y^2, {x + y == 1}}, {x, y}, Method -> "MOSEK"]`

Comment: Check `$HomeDirectory` path. Then check license path. Finally check license, maybe it has been corrupted.

Comment: I ran `FileNames["*", $HomeDirectory]` and the .lic file was within that list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been [resolved](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2538690) in Mathematica 13.3